# How to immediately auto-run electron windows app when someone closed it?

Tags: javascript, windows, electron

I am creating electron windows app for "Online Form Registration". if someone hardly closed this app then auto-run the .exe file immediately. please help me with this. Can we do this with javascript ? or electron have provided any such options to do that.

We have already tried this below mentioned codes but this functions are not working at all.

```
require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
  electron: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '.bin', 'electron'),
  hardResetMethod: 'exit'
});


var exec = require('child_process').exec
exec(process.argv.join(' ')) // execute the command that was used to run the app
app.quit() // quit the current app

function setKeyValue () {
  var regKey = new winreg({
      hive: winreg.HKCU,
      key: '\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run'
  });
  regKey.set('Your_Application_Name', winreg.REG_SZ, '"' + process.execPath + '"', function (err) {
      if (!err) {
        //notify user?
      }
  });


app.relaunch({ args: process.argv.slice(1).concat(['--relaunch']) })
```

Comment: *"...if someone hardly closed this app then auto-run the .exe file immediately..."* If the user closes the app, the app should not reopen itself. Reminds me of nefarious websites from the 90s.

Comment: Hi TJ, Can you help me in this....?